# Django request.user is becoming empty after login using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, django, cors, django-cors-headers

I have Django and angularjs app running separately. I am able to login to system by using angularjs. however after login request.user in django gives empty data.

```
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Login code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_for_new_design(request, *args, **kwargs):

if request.method == "POST":
    temp=json.loads(request.body)

    username = temp.get("username", None)
    password = temp.get("password", None)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    response_data = {}
    if user:
        login(request, user)
        response_data['success'] = True
        response_data['message'] = 'Login was succesfull!'
    else:  # invalid case
        response_data['success'] = True
        response_data['message'] = 'Login was Failure!'

response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data));
response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"
response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
return response
```

ajax method:

```
$http({
method:'POST',
url:uri,
datatype:"json",
data:payload,
headers: {

    'Content-Type': undefined
},

}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
    localStorage.setItem("username", $scope.username); 
    $state.go('app.main', {showLeftnav: true});     
},function(error){
    console.log(error)
})
```

Above two methods works fine.
But when I want test for if user is logged in or not using below method,

```
@csrf_exempt
def isAuthenticated_user(request):
    userdic = {};
    userdic['username'] = request.user.username
    print  userdic
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(userdic));
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
    return response


var csrftoken = $cookies.get('csrftoken')
authPromise = $http({
    'method': "POST",
    'url': "http://localhost:8000/isAuthenticated_user/",
     headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
         'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
         // 'withCredentials':true
    },

})
```

request.user gives empty data.

Kindly let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need send Authentication Token through AngularJS / Localstorage to Django DRF Authentication module.

Comment: I am using session based authentication

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ Follow this code snippet, you'll definitely find this useful.

Comment: I am not using Django rest framework, only plain Django

Comment: Oh! then it is not possible automatically to get user object,  you need to pass Token through headers and by using that token you need to retrieve user, This is State Less protocol my friend. It is pretty obvious that request.user is empty in your case.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
 user = self.request.query_params.get('username',None)
 print user
```

let me know if some error occured

Comment: getting this error AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: I have made a small edit in the answer, try this. its a line of code which worked in my project

Comment: that will solve script error, it will not get logged in user details

Comment: can you please provide the request and response details? 
I think the problem is where you send the request( I mean at the Ajax call may be)

Comment: already added in question, authPromise = $http({
    'method': "POST",
    'url': "http://localhost:8000/isAuthenticated_user/",
     headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
         'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
         // 'withCredentials':true
    },

})

Comment: That's the code you used to do the POST request. I asked you to provide the request and response shown in the browser console